# Elasticsearch query over multiple indexes very slow

Tags: database, elasticsearch, nosql, elastic-stack

**Question**: I create one index with one shard per day on Elasticsearch. When I perform queries against several days worth of these indices, it is very slow. Would anyone that has implemented a similar architecture give some guidance on what could be changed to make the queries more efficient?

**Description of the system:**

- Using [elasticsearch hot-warm-cold](https://www.elastic.co/pt/blog/implementing-hot-warm-cold-in-elasticsearch-with-index-lifecycle-management) architecture for [time-base indices](https://www.elastic.co/pt/blog/managing-time-based-indices-efficiently)
- One index of data per day of around 140MB
- One shard per index.
- An index stays in the hot phase for 1 day
- From day 1 to day 60 it is in the warm phase
- From day 60 to day 180 the index goes to the cold phase. After that it is deleted
- The health metrics of our ES cluster seem just fine. It doesn't seem to have too much CPU, Memory pressure

The machines on the cluster are described below. The **high IO** ones are used in the HOT phase. The **high storage** are used in the **warm and cold** phases. The data is replicated in two regions as shown in the picture.

[image]

**Description of the problem:**

When I do a query over these indexes, the query is very slow.  To illustrate that, I performed a query for a single *_id*. It takes more than 40 seconds. The image below is the the kibana output of that query.

[image]

It seems for me that ES does not perform the query of each index in parallel. Since when I go to the profiler, the total time it takes seem to be the sum of time times for each of the indices. Below there is the image reflecting the profiler result while also querying for the *_id*

[image]

also posted on the ES discussion forum: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-query-over-multiple-indexes-very-slow/216520

Comment: more details please: what is your cluster made of? no. of machines per ILM phase, roles, ram, cpu/cores? shard allocation activated?

Comment: @ibexit, I updated the question with how the cluster is sctructured. It seems for me that I am not getting something on how ES queries these indices. It seems like having too many indices are not a good idea in this case. However, I have seen posts on the internet about people using daily indices to store their data in this hot-warm-cold architecture

Comment: The approach is ok, we're storing TB of data per day in such layouts but much bigger ;) The Indices are indeed very small, cosider merging them into monthly indices in the warm phase, as shards loving it to be around 30-50GB in size. In that sweet spot the lucene plus file system overhead is well balanced with the amount of data to be searched. Q:You have removed the part before _search. Is this a wildcard index? An alias? Are you hitting frozen indices? I'm asking because 64 shards have been searched and thats more than hot+warm

Comment: @ibexit, that you very much for the reply. I am using the ILM alias to query the indices, so it should hit the indices in all the phases. The ES support said that we are hitting frozen indices, however, on the ILM we do not turn on the freeze. One thing that is bugging me is the queries on the indicies do not seem to happen in parallel. Maybe I really just have too many indices, for my kind of cluster and it can't handle it. What helps the confusing is the health metrics just don't show anything weird. The query just takes long.

Comment: In the meanwhile i had a look at the AWS specs: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/?nc1=h_ls. The cpu count is pretty low in your nodes. Have also a look on this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-reference-hardware.html It seems to me that the number of CPU/Cores is just to low for a shared infrastructure. And keep in mind, there are also docs incoming, what also takes some cpu.

Comment: Reduce the workload by merging daily indices into monthy ones or have a try with more powerfull nodes.

Comment: @ibexit, thank you for the time spent replying here. I am investigating how to merge these indices. For all that I could find, it seems that it cannot be done as part of the ILM. It needs to be done as a reindex. I am following this: https://blog.nviso.eu/2019/05/06/optimize-elasticsearch-for-security-log-collection-part-1-reducing-the-number-of-shards/

Answer (score 1):

For those who might have the same issue, I will post my solution.

My problem was the computers I was using to run ES. The **high storage** showed to be massively slower!

I changed the kind of deployment to use only **high IO** ones and didn't change anything else and it runs smoothly now.

Thanks @ibexit for the helpful feedback